# Error during LWC component constructor phase: [Illegal constructor.] Failing descriptor: {wave:analyticsSpinner}

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, lighting-out

I am using lightning out to show my anlaytics dashboard in external application, but I am facing this error

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Error during LWC component constructor phase: [Illegal constructor.] Failing descriptor: {wave:analyticsSpinner}

In application spinner is not showing earlier it is spinning and then dashboard appears now it is not so this error comes

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL"  extends="ltng:outApp" implements="ltng:allowGuestAccess">  
    <aura:dependency resource="c:showDashBoard" type="COMPONENT"/>
</aura:application>

<aura:component access="global" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" >
     <aura:attribute name="DashboardId" type="String" default=""/>
    <!--<aura:attribute name = "selectedDashboard" type="String" default=""/>-->
    <aura:attribute name="BuName" type="String" default=""/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>{!v.body}
</aura:component>
```

```js
({doInit : function(component, event, helper)
  {
   var deshBoardId = component.get('v.DashboardId'); 
     
   var XFilt= component.get('v.BuName'); 
   
   $A.createComponent("wave:waveDashboard",
       {
           "dashboardId": deshBoardId,
           "height": "650",
           "filter":XFilt
       },
       function(newcomponent)
       {
                        
            if (component.isValid()) 
            {
                 component.set("v.body", 
                     newcomponent);
            }
       }
    );
  }
})
```